# Why the first code is showing error but not the second one. What's happening here?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens

```
    address public owner = msg.sender;  //deployer
    uint public tokens = 10000;           
    mapping(address=>uint) balances;    //address=>tokens        
    
    balances[owner] = tokens;          //assigning all tokens 
                                       // to owner;
```

The above code shows error, but when put it into a ***constructor*** it does not show any ***error***

```
address public owner = msg.sender;
    uint public tokens = 10000;
    mapping(address=>uint) balances;
    
    constructor() {
       balances[owner] = tokens;
    }
```

Comment: You need a function to assign the mapping any key value pair. You can't directly assign any key value pair. Any kind of function will work be it a constructor or a normal function.
If you want the values to be assigned at the deployment then use constructor otherwise use a normal function.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `balances[owner] = tokens` is a statement, and you cannot put statements in the declaration are of storage variables. You can only declare variables and you are allowed to use simple expressions to assign values to some of those state variables while you declare them.

Check the following code, I put some invalid statements where it says `// Illegal`:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract Contract {

    address public owner = msg.sender;  //deployer
    uint public tokens = 10000;           
    mapping(address=>uint) balances;    //address=>tokens        
    
    balances[owner] = tokens; // Illegal
    tokens.push(5); // Illegal

    uint256 a = 5; // fine
    uint256 b = 6; // fine

    a + b; // Illegal

}
```

You can only put statements inside functions, modifiers, or in the constructor.

When declaring a state variable you are only allowed to assign a value to it in the same line you declare it.

To learn more about the differences among statements, expressions, declarations, etc., check here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351924/javascript-declarations-vs-expressions-vs-statements#:~:text=A%20declaration%20is%20a%20statement,and%20all%20declarations%20contain%20expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351924/javascript-declarations-vs-expressions-vs-statements#:%7E:text=A%20declaration%20is%20a%20statement,and%20all%20declarations%20contain%20expressions).